# Manually made physics for my player, but when airborne my motion is relative to rotation. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'll start off by saying I'm very new to Unity and C# and I'm attempting my first project after following a series of youtube tutorials. I manually made physics for my player (for acceleration, airborne velocity and drag, gravity, etc), but when I jump moving forward (or any other direction for that matter), when I rotate my character (through my mouse movement) my airborne movement changes relative to my rotation rather than remaining constant (I guess since it's moving in local space?). I'd like it so my airborne velocity gets influenced by my grounded velocity (that which is influenced by WASD), but doesn't move relative to my rotation, and i keep my movement direction no matter where I look.
I've been pouring overt my code for a while but I can't figure it out.
My player is called PlayerColliderParent, it has a Character Controller attached to it, along with my script PlayerColliderParentScript.cs (which handles all physics and movement for the player).

TLDR or if that was too confusing: When my player is airborne and moving, the direction of movement changes along with the player's rotation (where I look). I'd rather the direction remained constant regardless of the rotation.

Any help is appreciated as I really want to fix this.

Here is a video of the problem occuring: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpEMv059cZs

And here is PlayerColliderParentScript.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerColliderParentScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cameraRotation;
    public Vector3 directionalInput;
    public float accelerationAmount = 0.5f;
    public float maxSpeed = 6f;
    public float maxMoveSpeed =6f;
    public Vector3 directionalSpeed;
    public Vector3 airDirectionalSpeed;
    public float terminalVelocity = 30f;
    public float gravityStrength = 1f;
    public float currentYvel;
    public float airDrag;
    public float maxAirSpeed;
    public float jumpStrength = 1f;
    Vector3 gravityController;
    //Rigidbody playerBody = new Rigidbody();
    CharacterController controller = new CharacterController();
    
    //Rigidbody playerBody = new Rigidbody();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //playerBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //set acceleration factor
        float accelerationFactor = (accelerationAmount * 200) * Time.deltaTime;

        //rotate horizontally with camera
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, cameraRotation.localEulerAngles.y, 0);

        //JUMP or press against ground
        if (controller.isGrounded == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                currentYvel = jumpStrength;
            }
            else
            {
                currentYvel = -2f /** Time.deltaTime * 500*/;
            }
        }

        //accelerate while movement key is held
        //z axis
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            directionalInput.z = 1;
            if (directionalSpeed.z < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            directionalInput.z = -1;
            if (directionalSpeed.z < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.z > 0)
        {
            if (controller.isGrounded == true)
            {
                directionalInput.z = 0;
                directionalSpeed.z -= accelerationFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                directionalSpeed.z -= airDrag * Time.deltaTime * 100;
            }
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.z < 0)
        {
            if (controller.isGrounded == true)
            {
                directionalInput.z = 0;
                directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                directionalSpeed.z += airDrag * Time.deltaTime * 100;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            directionalInput.z = 0;
        }

        //x axis
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            directionalInput.x = 1;
            if (directionalSpeed.x < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            directionalInput.x = -1;
            if (directionalSpeed.x < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.x > 0)
        {
            if (controller.isGrounded == true)
            {
                directionalInput.x = 0;
                directionalSpeed.x -= accelerationFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                directionalSpeed.x -= airDrag * Time.deltaTime * 100;
            }
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.x < 0)
        {
            if (controller.isGrounded == true)
            {
                directionalInput.x = 0;
                directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                directionalSpeed.x += airDrag * Time.deltaTime * 100;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            directionalInput.x = 0;
        }

        //accelerate downwards if not grounded
        if (controller.isGrounded == false)
        {
            if (currentYvel > -terminalVelocity)
            {
                currentYvel -= gravityStrength * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        //Reset gravity vecctor
        gravityController = Vector3.zero;

        //calculate movement velocity
        Vector3 direction = directionalInput.normalized;
        float velocityX = direction.x * Mathf.Round(directionalSpeed.x);
        float velocityY = (currentYvel / 2) * Time.deltaTime;
        float velocityZ = direction.z * Mathf.Round(directionalSpeed.z);
        Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(velocityX * Time.deltaTime, velocityY, velocityZ * Time.deltaTime);

        //check for sprint key
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            velocity *= 1.5f;
        }

        //move player according to velocity
        controller.Move(transform.TransformDirection(velocity));

        //set airspeed the same as character velocity
        airDirectionalSpeed.x = velocityX * Time.deltaTime;
        airDirectionalSpeed.y = 0;
        airDirectionalSpeed.z = velocityZ * Time.deltaTime;
        if (airDirectionalSpeed.x > 0)
        {
            airDirectionalSpeed.x -= airDrag * Time.deltaTime * 100;
        }
        if (airDirectionalSpeed.z > 0)
        {
            airDirectionalSpeed.z -= airDrag * Time.deltaTime * 100;
        }
        airDirectionalSpeed = transform.TransformDirection(airDirectionalSpeed);
        Vector3 airVelocity = new Vector3(airDirectionalSpeed.x, 0, airDirectionalSpeed.z);
        Vector3 airMoveAmountX = new Vector3((airVelocity.x / 3), 0, 0);
        Vector3 airMoveAmountZ = new Vector3(0, 0, (airVelocity.z / 3));       

        //move player according to airspeed
        if (controller.isGrounded == false)
        {
            if (airDirectionalSpeed.x < maxAirSpeed | airDirectionalSpeed.x > -maxAirSpeed)
            {
                controller.Move(airMoveAmountX);
            }
            if (airDirectionalSpeed.z < maxAirSpeed | airDirectionalSpeed.z > -maxAirSpeed)
            {
                controller.Move(airMoveAmountZ);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part smells:

```
void Update()
{
    // (...)
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        directionalInput.x = 1;
        if (directionalSpeed.x < maxSpeed)
        {
            directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor;
        }
    }
    //(...)
}
```

If your are not grounded, you shouldn't be responding to directional inputs and accelerating in horizontal direction. Same applies for the corresponding logic for the other 3 directional keys.

You can try to add a condition to only execute this logic if the player is grounded.

Comment: thing is, I still want to be able to influence my motion in the air
and i tried it anyway, but it doesn't really solve my problem
im pretty sure it has something to do with world space/local space conversions

Comment: That means I didn't really understood your problem. Can you try to edit the question to make it clearer on "What are you trying to achieve?"

Comment: there, added a little clarification section, hopefully that's easier to understand
thanks for your help :)